# Using numpy and if statements

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement

I wish to create a 2D numpy array and I want to get the mean of only the arrays where the 2 values are the same. Example when it is [1, 1] or [2, 2] etc for values between 1 and 6. Here is the code I have so far. But I got stuck in the if statement section.

```
q5=np.random.randint(7,size=(15,2))
print(q5)
for i in q5:
    if i[0]=i[1]:
    # I am clueless on how to continue
```

Comment: I recommend that you learn about broadcasting in numpy. Generally you don't write for loops or if statements with numpy. Instead, use broadcasting.

Comment: `q5[q5[:,0]==q5[:,1]].mean()`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice no broadcasting concept here... you probably meant advanced indexing?

Comment: `=` is for assignation, as you have used it in the first lines of your code. `==` is for _equal_.

Comment: `if` statements only work with scalar True/False values.  Don't use arrays in an if, otherwise you'll get an 'ambiguity' error.

Comment: @Julien Perhaps...and also I had in mind doing it in multiple steps not just a single line.

Answer (score -3):

In your code, you made a syntax mistake in the if condition. The comparison operator is `==` not `=`.

But as an answer, use a list comprehension to select the desired arrays and then calculate the mean of the selected arrays.

Here's the code you can use for this problem:

```py
import numpy as np

q5 = np.random.randint(1, 7, size=(15,2))
print(q5)

identical_values = [i for i in q5 if i[0] == i[1]]

if identical_values:
    mean_value = np.mean(identical_values)
    print(mean_value)
else:
    print("There isn't any row with identical values.")
```

Comment: With numpy, you can do this more simply (and it will run faster) without for loops or list comprehensions.